# Draw selection Area in WinForm Application

Tags: c#, winforms

In my WinForm I need to draw selection area on the screen. User should be able to drag selected rectangle on corners or border to resize. As below:

[image]

> I could draw the rectangle with solid brush. 
>   How can I make it resizeable when dragging from border or corner?

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    using (Graphics g = this.panel1.CreateGraphics()) {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(this.panel1.BackColor);

        g.FillRectangle(brush, this.panel1.Bounds); 
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, e.X, e.Y, 20, 20);

        pen.Dispose();
        brush.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you have to draw and handle them all together! There is no easy or quick way of doing this as far as I know. And, it's not that hard, you just draw these little rectangles around your bigger rectangle and then calculate the mouse location in comparison to their location and then you can trigger your resize code. BTW, use PictureBox instead of a panel.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `MouseDown`, I think you can use `MouseMove`.

At first, this event checks if left button is pressed:

```
if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)) { 

    //Check for the position of your mouse 
}
```

Now you will put some `if`statement to be sure you will redraw your rectangle depending on your little resize boxes. Every `if` will recalculate the rectangle, erasing the old one and plotting the newest. 
Hope this helps.