# How do I make a Auto-Filling Function for my DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I would like to Auto-Fill text from a cell into cells I selected.

This should work like in MS Excel:

[image: Write Text into the Cell]

[image: Text Auto-Fill into the selceted cells after realeasing the mouse (like in excel)]

It would be very nice, if someone could give me atleast a little hint how I could do this.

Comment: The images you have shown are Excel, and not a DataGrid, please show your code, and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: The problem is that i dont know where to start.

Comment: You need some sort of [custom draw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22552028/1997232) while selecting cells and some cue (little arrow?) to give user a hint what he can select it like this. After mouse is released take initial cell value, transform it somehow and fill into all selected cells. Too broad task for a single question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will try something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround that achieve it via left clicking and dropping down drag the mouse down when `shift` pressed.

First, define a variable to save the `shift status` and modify it when pressed.

```
bool shiftpressed = false;

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)
    {
        shiftpressed = true;
    }
}
```

Then change the text of cells that you selected and reset `shiftpressed`.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (shiftpressed)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell i in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {
            i.Value = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count - 1].Value;
        }
    }
    shiftpressed = false;
}
```

Besides, add `this.KeyPreview = true` in the constructor.

The result demo,

[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks (a little late i know)